# Cannot connect to rstudio ubuntu server

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I started with a bare-metal server, installed ubuntu server 13.04, then apache, then php5. I have installed rstudio and when I use the command to verify installation I get `rstudio-server start/running, process <number>` where <number> changes each time. However, when I go to <server-ip>:8787 my browser tells me it cannot connect.

I am told by admin that 8787 is open. I also used `netstat -lanp | grep 8787` and got the following `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8787  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2963/rserver` and nothing else.

Comment: For what do you need the Apache? Are you running rstudio behind a proxy? What is the output of `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation`? Do you have access to the log files, i.e. `cat /var/log/user.log | grep rstudio` and `cat /var/log/syslog | grep rstudio`? Can you access rstudio from localhost, i.e. `lynx localhost:8787`? What is the http status code?

Comment: wow, just been alerted to your answer today! Sorry I figured this out in the end by using apache to proxy port 8787 to port 80.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out in the end by using apache to proxy port 8787 to port 80

Comment: Can you post the solution step by step?

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar problem today. I could connect to Rstudio-server by *localhost:8787*, but it failed when using *http://<\ip>:8787*, both from the server machine and from other computers.
The solution is simple in my case:
In the rserver configuration doc */etc/rstudio/rserver.conf*, there was a line:
*www-address=127.0.0.1*
just delete or comment it out. Then everything works well.
Have no idea when and how this line was added though. It shouldn't be there by default according to the official document.

Answer (score 0):

trouble shoot 3:

1, open firewall for port 8787

```
sudo ufw allow 8787
```

2, check internet explore

```
lynx http://<ip>:8787
```

3, force restart and try again

```
rstudio-server restart
```

if you still can not connect to Rstudio server:

```
.............
```